# SQL SSIS pick and chose data to make a table row

Tags: ssis, transform, rows, multiple-columns

I have a table that is recording visitor searches.

```
SessionID   From          Region   DateSelected
12345       2014-10-12    NULL     2014-10-01 13:00
12345       NULL          Devon    2014-10-01 13:26
12345       NULL          Cornwall 2014-10-01 13:28
```

I've been asked to create a new table from an SSIS package to transform this data into combined table picking the best data from each column.

So using the above table I want to produce something that looks like this:

```
SessionID   From          Region   DateSelected
12345       2014-10-12    Cornwall 2014-10-01 13:28
```

So I'm picking the column with a From date for a particular session ID and then the Region Cornwall because its not null and its the most recent DateSelected.

Now, I'm not sure if this can be done using ssis but if you have any ideas I'd be really grateful.

Cheers,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You have data in table, so use source element with sql query:

**[sqlfiddleexample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99525/4)**

```
select top 1 t1.SessionID,
             t2.[From],
             t1.Region,
             t1.DateSelected
from table1 t1
left join (select sessionid, max([From]) [From]
           from table1
           group by sessionid) t2
on t2.sessionid = t1.sessionid
where t1.Region is not null
order by t1.DateSelected desc
```

result:

```
| SESSIONID |       FROM |   REGION |                   DATESELECTED |
|-----------|------------|----------|--------------------------------|
|     12345 | 2014-10-12 | Cornwall | October, 01 2014 13:28:00+0000 |
```